# How to get left join data using multiple condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two table

```
master_document_table   document_table
id | title              id | master_document_id | userId
1  |  Profile

select * from master_document_table as md
left join document_table as d on md.id = d.master_document_id and d.userId = 2
```

Result:

```
id | title     | master_document_id | userId
1  |  Profile      null                null
```

how can this be achieved using mongodb i have tried & also did some research from stack overflow and did not got the expected result.

Comment: check [mongodb aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I some how managed to get desire result thanks for the help

```
db.master_document_table.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'document_table',
        localField: 'id',
        foreignField: 'master_document_id',
        as: 'users'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        title: 1,
        users: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$users',
            as: 'user',
            cond: {
              $eq: ['$$user.userId', 2]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From mongo v3.2, it is possible to aggregate two or more than two collections.
But here one thing, you need to know is, you won't get the same structure as sql. You will get your data on nested document.

Your tables will look something like this in mongodb:

**master_document_table (collection / table)**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada45f702"),
  title: "Profile",
}
```

**document_table (collection / table)**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada45e790"),
  master_document_id: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada45f702"), // master_doc_table's ref id.
  userId: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada327f231"), // user's ref id.
}
```

Your query will be:

```
db.document_table.aggregate([
   {$match: {title: "Profile"}},   // you can give any condition here.
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "master_document_table",
         localField: "master_document_id",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "master_document_id"
       }
  }
])
```

Your query result will look something like:

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada45e790"),
  master_document_id: {
      _id: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada45f702"),
      title: "Profile"
  },
  userId: ObjectId("5f28d53c00613e6ada327f231"),
}]
```

Now you can restructure it based on your requirement.
I would like to recommend you
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
&
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
article from mongodb docs.

Hope this will help to resolve your problem.

Comment: here the document table can be empty and the match by user id won't work if the document table is empty the result will be empty array

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to join two tables you can use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operator in version 3.6 and newer. Since you need the results like LEFT OUTER JOIN, you have to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array to objects and filter out the desired results using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) conditions (ie `document_table.userId = 2`). Dont forget to use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` to **true** when unwinding.

Sample code for reference:

```
db.master_document_table.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "document_table",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "master_document_id",
      "as": "document_table"
    }},
    { $unwind: { path: "$document_table", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        $match:{
            $or:[
                { "document_table": { $exists: false } },
                {"document_table.userId" : 2 }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: document not limited to userId getting all results for multiple userId

Comment: didn't understand. If matched results has another userId other than 2, it will filter those results out. Could you share some more details, if that doesn't give your expected result?

Comment: document_master = type of document.   

document = user will upload document and identify the type using document_master.

first case would be the user has not uploaded any document if so need the type of document from document_master.

second case would be the user as uploaded the document get that document along with the type of document from ducument_master.  

there would be multiple users filter by userId.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $builder = $this->createAggregationBuilder();
    $builder
        ->match()
            ->field('userLogin')->notEqual($currentLogin)
        ->lookup('wm_intersection')
            ->localField('userLogin')
            ->foreignField('wm2')
            ->alias('wmIntersections')
        ->project()
        ->includeFields(['userLogin', 'wmIntersections', 'requestDate', 'wmIntersection'])
        ->excludeFields(['wmIntersections'])
        ->filter(
            '$wmIntersections',
            'wmIntersection',
            $builder->expr()->addAnd(
                $builder->expr()->eq('$$wmIntersection.wm1', $currentLogin),
                $builder->expr()->eq('$$wmIntersection.field', $field),
                $builder->expr()->eq('$$wmIntersection.value', $value)
            )
        )
        ->group()
            ->field('id')
            ->expression('$userLogin')
            ->field('requestDate')
            ->min('$requestDate')
            ->field('wmIntersections')
            ->min('$wmIntersections');

    return $builder->getAggregation()->getIterator();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).